# Local Networking with Hostname in Android

Tags: java, android, networking, local, hostname

I'm working as Mobile Developer. I am looking for a way that is works as connection to a backend server with computer name/hostname but It is confused situation. Android does not understand or solve the hostnames. Are there any way to solve this problem ?

e.g:

Networking with http://192.168.1.10:9000 works as well.

Networking with http://DESKTOP-599U766:9000 does not work as well.

Comment: Ask yourself: how is your Android device supposed to understand what DESKTOP-599U766 is? With the IP-address your phone knows exactly where to connect to.

Comment: This question is about inspiration. "Scanning the IP's and discover which one is DESKTOP-599U766" will be maybe good point, know what I mean ? @Zun

Comment: That is what DNS is for. DNS resolves names to IP addresses, which is necessary for networking because packets have addresses, not names, in the packet header.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, any device connected to your local network ought to be resolving hostnames through that network's own DNS. In practice, Android has painted itself into a corner here because it defaults to using a hardcoded external DNS, with only the option of selecting an alternate external DNS with its own hostname (it won't permit you to select your router's IP address). I believe the intention is to prevent a malicious wifi network from providing a bogus hostname for software updates and the like, but it's still frustrating.